# SQL Server - Change job environment

Tags: sql-server, ssis

A short question I have, but not much information I could find:

I have this job with multiple SSIS steps in SQL server 2014. All these job steps have the same environment, which contains 2 connection strings.

Is it possible to change the environment at once for all the steps in one particular job, instead of choosing the environment one by one for each step in that job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Configuration pane is specific to an individual job step.  If you have multiple steps, you need to configure them each separately.

If you want to have the Environment controlled in one location, consider having a Master SSIS package that is run by the job.  Within the master package, you can then fire off the other individual SSIS steps, and let each of them inherit the environment-specific configurations from the master package.